# Loading Directory in SQLContext in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to load a directory with sub directories with files inside into sql context but am getting this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://nameservice1/osa/bankrtl/mde/mde_event_stream_anon.dat/*
```

and I run the scala code like this:

```
val df = sqlContext.load("hdfs://nameservice1/osa/bankrtl/mde/mde_event_stream_anon.dat/*")
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is inside the directory? Are these hadoop part files with a specific structure or is it just a conglomoration of different formats?

Comment: oh..just hadoop part files...all have the same format